# Request de API não funcionando no ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, postman

Estou tendo problema ao testar meus end-points com o post e asp.net core 2.1.

> Controller Base

```
public class ControladorBase : Controller
{
    protected IMapper _Mapper;

    public ControladorBase()
    {

    }

    public ControladorBase(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _Mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Cartao")]
public class CartaoController : ControladorBase
{
    ICartaoBusiness _cartaoBusiness;

    public CartaoController(ICartaoBusiness cartaoBusiness)
    {
        _cartaoBusiness = cartaoBusiness;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Cartao/AddOrUpdate")]
    public IActionResult AddOrUpdate([FromBody]CartaoModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Cartao cartao = _Mapper.Map<CartaoModel, Cartao>(model);

            if (model.CartaoId.HasValue)
            {
                _cartaoBusiness.Update(cartao);
            }
            {
                _cartaoBusiness.Insert(cartao);
            }

            return new JsonResult(new { Success = true });
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult(new { Success = false });
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Cartao/Teste")]
    public IActionResult Teste()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { Success = false });
    }
}
```

> StartUp

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AberturaDeContasContext>(
            options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data Source=3Y1S0L2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AberturaDeContas;User ID=sa;Password=abc102030!;"
        ));

        services.AddTransient<ICartaoBusiness, CartaoBusiness>();
        services.AddTransient<IProspectBusiness, ProspectBusiness>();

        services.AddAutoMapper();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Configurando o serviço de documentação do Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new Info
                {
                    Title = "Abertura de Contas Digital",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "API REST criada com o ASP.NET Core",
                    Contact = new Contact
                    {
                        Name = "Kaio Nylander",
                    }
                });

            string caminhoAplicacao =
                PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            string nomeAplicacao =
                PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationName;
            //string caminhoXmlDoc =
            //    Path.Combine(caminhoAplicacao, $"{nomeAplicacao}.xml");

            //c.IncludeXmlComments(caminhoXmlDoc);
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }            

        app.UseDefaultFiles();            
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


        // Ativando middlewares para uso do Swagger
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
                "Abertura de Contas Digital");
        });

    }
}
```

> Program

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var db = services.GetRequiredService<AberturaDeContasContext>();
                db.Database.Migrate();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating the database.");
            }
        }
        webHost.Run();            
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:5051")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Erro na chamada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está enviando o POST pelo postman utilizando qual opção da aba Body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou retirando o atributo "Route" e colocando a rota no próprio atributo HttpPost?

```
[HttpPost("AddOrUpdate")]
public IActionResult AddOrUpdate([FromBody]CartaoModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você nomeou errado as actions do controller.
Ao invés de disso:

```
[Route("api/Cartao/AddOrUpdate")]
```

Use assim:

```
[Route("AddOrUpdate")]
```

Você não deve repetir o api/Cartao que está explícito no controller.